# Finite-Dimensional Elementary Cylinder vs. Finite-Dimensional Cylinder

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm currently reading *Theory of Probability and Random Processes* by Koralov and Sinai. In Chapter 2, the authors state the definition of a *finite-dimensional elementary cylinder* and a *finite-dimensional cylinder*:

> Consider a probability space, $(X,\mathcal{G}, P_X)$.
>
> Let $1 \leq n \leq \infty$ and $\Omega$ be the space of sequences of length $n$. A *finite-dimensional elementary cylinder* is a set of the form
> $$ A = \{\omega: \omega_{t_1} \in A_1,\ldots, \omega_{t_k} \in A_k\}, $$
> where $t_1,\ldots,t_k\geq 1$ and $A_i \in \mathcal{G}$, $1 \leq i \leq k$.
> A *finite-dimensional cylinder* is a set of the form $$A = \{\omega: (\omega_{t_1},\ldots,\omega_{t_k}) \in B\},$$ where $t_1,\ldots,t_k \geq 1$ and $B \in \mathcal{G} \times \ldots\times \mathcal{G}$ ($k$ times).

What is the difference between these two definitions?

I don't really understand how these two definitions are different. My understanding is that a finite-dimensional elementary cylinder is essentially the finite Cartesian product of sets in your $\sigma$-algebra. And a finite-dimensional cylinder is an element in the Cartesian product of the entire $\sigma$-algebra, which is just the Cartesian product of some elements in the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between sets of the form $A\times B$ where $A$ and $B$ are Borel sets in $\mathbb R$ and Borel sets in $\mathbb R^{2}$?

Comment: geetha290krm: If A. Sun does not respond, could you explain it anyway because the notion of cylinders  has always caused me problems when trying to understand theorems that refer to cylinders. Thanks.

Comment: The set of all Cartesian products of sets in the $\sigma$-algebra is not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra, whereas the Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by the aforementioned set. 

I understand the difference now between the cylinders. I'm used to seeing $\mathcal{G} \otimes \mathcal{G} \otimes \ldots$ as the product $\sigma$-algbera. Thank you.